# TextBox getting cleared before item gets added to the List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a strongly typed textbox in View and there is an ADD button.

User enters description in TextBox and clicks ADD. This description is added to a List.

After adding to the list, I want to clear this TextBox.

When I used ModelState.Clear, it cleared the entire model including the List because it is also part of ViewModel.

When I use client side javascript function, the textbox gets cleared before the ADD functionality is complete.

How to first add the value to the list and later clear the textbox using javascript?

To clear using jQuery I used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $("#AddButton").click(function() {
        $("#textbox1").val("");
     });
</script>
```

Comment: It's really depends how you use your script or/and 3rd part. libraries. Would you please post your JavaScript here?

Comment: @vzayko sample code added in original post.

Comment: Works for Me :   --> To clear Textbox After Any Event -->$('#AddButton').click(function () { $('#textbox1').val('');  });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take on hidden filed of model property.

```html
     @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.prop)
```

and use normal textbox

```html
<input type="text" id="textbox1" />
```

now while clicking add first assign value to hidden and after clear text box

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
     $("#AddButton").click(function() {
       $("#prop").val($("#textbox1").val()); 
       $("#textbox1").val("");
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This JS function just clear your field but don't update your model. You can't update MVC Model from JS directly because it is already converted to plain HTML on server side. From this point, you have three approaches:

1. Server side: don't use ModelState.Clear but ModelState.Remove instead. In this case you can specify what part of your model you want to remove.
2. Client side (more work): don't use MVC models at all but load and update your data dynamically by JS. In this case I would use some 3rd part. libraries like [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) or [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/).
3. Client side (don't suggest): post new value back to server side using JQuery (e.g. $.ajax({...})), in case of success, update your HTML page from script(JQuery also helps).

Note: last two approaches might require additional security work. So I would suggest to play with the first one.

Comment: I don't want to clear the model from client side only the textbox should get blank.

Comment: You can also handle your form submit event: $('#formname').submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    this.submit(); 
    $("#textbox1").val("");
});

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add value in MVC `model` from `jQuery`.
But one thing you can do.

- Just crate `list` type model `class` and add controls on page with
  model compatible name.
- After that when you `post` your page you will get all the records in
  `list`.